# Problemas con EF en el siguiente codigo

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Tengo un metodo el cual es llamado en el constructor de mi controller Home en el creo roles al iniciar la aplicacion y le asigno un rol especifico a un usuario, pasa que no me crea ningun registro en la db, ademas al depurar el codigo me doy cuenta que se salta intrucciones o simplemente no las ejecuta todas y se corta en x instruccion (no me arroja ningun error) y la aplicación en si sigue funcionando.

Mi metodo

```
private async Task CreateRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        //obtener servicios del role manager
        var roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        var userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();

        String[] rolesName = { "Admin", "User" };

        foreach (var item in rolesName)
        {
            var roleExist = await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(item);

            if (!roleExist)
            {
                await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(item));
            }

        }

        var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync("027166cf-2757-4f96-9dc1-5d83bb8c0716");
        await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");

    }
```

Al ejecutarse este metodo ejecuta hasta esta linea:

```
var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync("027166cf-2757-4f96-9dc1-5d83bb8c0716");
```

Y lo que sigue no lo ejecuta. De vez en cuando al darle en reiteradas veces f5 pasa finalmente por la línea que faltaría, la que me debería crear mis roles con el usuario pero aún así no los crea en la db.

Como también existen veces que el programa o la depuración se corta en esta línea:

```
var roleExist = await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(item);
```

(sin arrojar errores, disculpen por ser majadero con esto)

Mi constructor del controller Home

```
public HomeController(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        CreateRoles(serviceProvider);
    }
```

Parte de mi startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        //services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
        //    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }
```

Estoy usando VS 2017 Community con SQL Server 2008 r2

¿Alguien sabe a que se debe este problema que no ejecute todas las líneas del código y se corte antes de terminar el programa? Señalo nuevamente que no me da ningún error ni el código ni en la aplicación.

Comment: Brother es un poco dificil ayudarte porque no tengo acceso a la base, pero eso que se salte instrucciones supongo que es por los eventos asincrónicos. Deberías documentarte un poco con tasks y promesas

Comment: A mi me da que el error está situado en la linea `await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");` No validas si `user` es `null`

Comment: Hermano, creo que necesitas repasar un poco más sobre Inyección de dependencias, vas por buen camino, esto te dará más ideas: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/560798/ASP-NET-MVC-Controller-Dependency-Injection-for-Be